# Cypress | How to only log elements that contain a string?

Tags: cypress

I only want to log elements that contain any type of string.
As of now log looks like this:
[LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NFAX.png)

and my code looks like this:
[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLvno.png)

How can I only display elements with string?
Thanks

Comment: Please avoid sharing logs and code as images. Read this first: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var dict = {} //create a new object
cy.get('#chunker')
  .find('.row')
  .find('#label')
  .each(($ele, index) => {
    const value = $ele.text().trim().replace()
    if (value) {
      dict[index] = value //key is the index
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    //print just the values in the dict:
    for (var key in dict) {
      cy.log(dict[key])
    }

    //Print key value pairs in the dict
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)) {
      cy.log('Key: ' + key, 'Value: ' + value)
    }
  })
```

You should get logs like this:

[image: dictionary print]

Comment: how can I give them all a value? Like in a dict {key: value, key2: value}?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `:not(:empty)` to the label selector

```js
cy.get('#chunker')
  .find('.row')
  .find('#label:not(:empty)')
  .each(($label) => {
    const value = $label.text().trim().replace();
    cy.log(value)
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

To make a dictionary with *original* positions as the key, use `.reduce()`.

```js
  cy.get('#chunker')
  .find('.row #label')
  .then($labels => {
    return [...$labels].reduce((dict,label,index) => {   // loop over labels
      const text = label.innerText.trim().replace()      // transform 
      if (text) {                                        // test if empty
        dict[index] = text                               // add to dict
      }
      return dict
    }, {})
  })
  .then(dict => {
    for (const index in dict) {
      cy.log(index, dict[index])
    }
  })
```

gives

```js
log 1, Sprinkler2
log 8, sprinkler1
log 15, Carl.2
log 22, Carl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally `cy.log()` based on if `value` has a [truthy value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

```js
cy.get('#chunker')
  .find('.row')
  .find('#label')
  .each(($ele, index) => {
    const value = $ele.text().trim().replace();
    if (value) { cy.log(value) }
  });
```